# Phusion Passenger SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at passenger _start_

Tags: node.js, passenger

I'm trying to install https://github.com/zadam/trilium.git on my A2 shared hosting server. The instructions for cPanel and SSH terminal both show a start command like:

```
passenger start --app-type node ./trilium/src/www app.js
```

But everything I try reports:

```
App 15779 output: passenger start --app-type node ./trilium/src/www app.js
App 15779 output:           ^^^^^
App 15779 output: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
App 15779 output:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
...
```

I'm new to Passenger, and don't have direct access to its setup. The techs at the hosting service seem equally lost. How can a statement that is recommended in all the help files fail at the first command?

Maybe it highlights *start* if any of the following parameters are wrong?
Maybe the command is being stored in the wrong location? But it finds that command when I try to Start Passenger...

Answer (score 0):

That unhelpful error message, and a lot of similar ones, seems to have resulted from an initial failure to "npm install" my package.

When I tried a clean start of the whole process, using the terminal instead of cPanel, I had access to the logs from npm, and I found this:

```
...
> better-sqlite3@7.4.3 install /home/psychoro/trilium/node_modules/better-sqlite3
> prebuild-install || npm run build-release

prebuild-install WARN install /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/psychoro/trilium/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node)

> better-sqlite3@7.4.3 build-release /home/psychoro/trilium/node_modules/better-sqlite3
> node-gyp rebuild --release
```

The session locked up there, and the system would not let me open another terminal to investigate. I resorted to ^C and my terminal access was restored. I suspect that corresponds to the event during my initial install when I was using cPanel and the access to all of it locked up with no explanation.

So all the useless error messages I saw later were produced by an installation that had crashed midway.

It does seem like "WARN" is a bit bland for a condition that kills the install and leaves chaos behind. And that "npm install" should be able to survive a missing file reference...  But I suppose that isn't Phusion's responsibility...

Oh, and my command above was wrong:

passenger start --app-type node ./trilium/src/www app.js

should have been:

passenger start --app-type node --startup-file ./trilium/src/www

The guide I was following back then made it seem like "--startup-file" was a placeholder to be replaced by the name of my package's file. Still doesn't explain why it errored on "start" instead of my obvious error.
...